# My web turn on witch docker-compose.yml but not my dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, prestashop

I work on a deployement of Prestashop image but when i use `docker-compose up -d --build` it work. I have access to Prestashop install page. But when i do `build -t prestashop:latest .` to build it and use `docker run -d --name prestashop -p 80:80 prestashop:latest` to run it. I fall on the apache homepage. Thank you in advance

Dockerfile
FROM ubuntu:18.04

```
RUN \
sed -i 's/# \(.*multiverse$\)/\1/g' /etc/apt/sources.list && \
apt-get update && \
apt-get -y upgrade && \
apt-get install -y build-essential && \
apt-get install -y software-properties-common && \
apt-get install -y byobu curl git htop man unzip vim wget && \
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade
RUN apt-get install -y apache2 libapache2-mod-php
RUN apt install -y php unzip
RUN apt-get install -y php-cli php-common php-mbstring php-gd php-intl php-xml php-mysql php-zip php-curl php-xmlrpc
COPY . /var/www/html:rw
COPY ./config/presta.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
RUN a2enmod rewrite

WORKDIR /var/www/html

EXPOSE 80
CMD apachectl -D FOREGROUND
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
    
    mysql:
        image: mysql:5.7
        env_file:
        - .env
        volumes:
        - ./.docker/data/mysql/:/var/lib/mysql
        - ./.docker/logs/mysql/:/var/log/mysql
        ports:
        - "3306:3306"
        container_name: presta_mysql
    
    phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        ports:
        -  8080:80
        env_file:
        - .env
        environment:
            PMA_HOST: mysql
            VIRTUAL_HOST: phpmyadmin.presta.local  
        container_name: presta_phpmyadmin

    app_dev:
        container_name: presta_app
        build: .
        environment:
        - VIRTUAL_HOST=app.presta.local
        volumes : 
        - ./:/var/www/html:rw
        restart: always
        ports:
        - 80:80
        links:
        - "mysql:presta_mysql"
```

Comment: Your image's `COPY` instruction copies into a container directory named `/var/www/html:rw`.  You don't notice this in the Compose setup because you have `volumes:` that mount different content on to `/var/www/html`, and the `:rw` suffix is taken as an option.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I don't understand what I have to do. To solve this problem.

Comment: Try running `docker run --rm -it prestashop bash`, and in the interactive shell that gives you, `ls /var/www`.  What directory names are there?

Answer (score 1):

Before you go into it, I recommend you to read docker documentation.
There are a few main topics you need to understand first:
https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

[image]

```
version: '2'
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    env_file: 
      - .env
    volumes:
      - "./.docker/data/mysql/:/var/lib/mysql:rw"
      - "./.docker/logs/mysql/:/var/log/mysql:rw"
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    container_name: presta_mysql

phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    ports:
      -  "8080:80"
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
        PMA_HOST: mysql
        VIRTUAL_HOST: phpmyadmin.presta.local  
    container_name: presta_phpmyadmin

app_dev:
    container_name: presta_app
    build: .
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=app.presta.local
    volumes : 
      - "./:/var/www/html:rw"
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    links:
      - "mysql:presta_mysql"
```